# Why I can't add a CSS style in this WordPress theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a CSS style to a WordPress theme that I am developing as is shown in this tutorial: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/ but seems don't work and I cant' understand why.

So this is the **head.php** file of my personal theme:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> » Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" /> <!-- leave this for stats -->

<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
-->
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<!-- <?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js.js"></script>
<!--
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
    if(f)
    {
        write_css('<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>');
    }
</script>
-->

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">

<h1><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
<div class="description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>
</div>
<hr />
```

And in my **functions.php** file I have put the following code:

```
<?php
function wpb_adding_styles() {
    wp_register_script('my_stylesheet', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script('my_stylesheet');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles');
?>
```

But the file **style.css** is not loaded. Why? What am I missing?

In particular the thing that I can't understand in the previous tutorial is how and hwere the **wpb_adding_styles()** is called because in the **header.php** file it is never called.

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: It would be `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style` instead of  `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: try this: `wp_register_style( 'my_stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri() );
`

Comment: @andreivictor where I have to put it? into my wpb_adding_styles() function?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Yes ofcourse place it in the function.

Comment: @RahilWazir don't work

Comment: @AndreaNobili Can you show us the updated code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply paste this code:

```
<?php
function wpb_adding_styles() {
    wp_register_style('my_stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('my_stylesheet');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles');
?>
```

**Problem with your code:**
[plugins_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) it actually prints `http://example.com/wp-content/plugins`
instead of
 `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme`

Use [get_stylesheet_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri) as it retrieves
`http://example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css`

Don't know why the tutorial used [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for stylesheet as both used for Javascript files. Use [wp_register_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) for css files.

Comment: Yes. That tutorial's simply wrong. Note that for `wp_register_style()`/`wp_enqueue_style()` to work, you need to call [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) in the `<head>` section of your template. (Alternatively you could skip using the script enqueueing and include the stylesheet in your template, and not bother doing anything in `functions.php`. That the approach taken in the "HTML5 compliant head area" example in [the official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) on Theme development.)

Comment: @MattGibson Great one!

Answer (score 0):

Your reference for your stylesheet (`style.css`) was not correct. The `plugins_url` function is for WP plugins, but you are trying to develop a WP theme.

Put this code into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function wpb_adding_styles() {
     wp_register_script('my_stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri() );
     wp_enqueue_script('my_stylesheet');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use of this in your `functions.php`

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

And add this into your `header.php`

```
<?php wp_enqueue_scripts(); ?>
```

Just replace names and address. If you need to add more than 1 `.css` or `.js` just copy and make new line.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of _andreivictor_'s answer

Comment: Oh ya!! :-) just i saw that.  BTW I think his problem is about appearance and I wrote that how to do!.